# getimagesize ... failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, fopen, getimagesize

When I try to get the size of an image it returns false and I receive this warning:

```
$img_size = getimagesize($img_dir.$image_name.'0.jpg');
var_dump($img_size); // returns bool false
```

> Warning:
>   getimagesize(http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/devices/mk10_0.jpg):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
>   in

My first thought was the path to the image was incorrect but I tried the url in an image tag and it loaded the image just fine

```
echo '<img src="'.$img_dir.$image_name.'0.jpg" alt="">';
```

I don't know if it would be relevant to this question but before I received this warning I was having issues with the same line of code with how PHP was setup, I had to update my `php.ini` variable `allow_url_fopen=1`

Could there be more to do on my PHP setup?

**EDIT**
This code doesn't solve the problem but is an alternate way to get the image size information without throwing an error / waring.

```
$img_data = file_get_contents($img_path.$image_name.'0.jpg');
$size = getimagesizefromstring($img_data);
```